# Prove that $n$ an odd number divides $2^{n!}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If any of you could help me start this problem I would be most grateful! Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [Euler's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Comment: Many ways to skin this cat. Anyway, your question falls a bit short of what we expect. Please check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Answer (score 1):

Since $a\mid b$ implies $(2^{a}-1) \mid (2^b-1)$, $2^{n!}-1$ is a multiple of any number of the form $2^k-1$ with $1\leq k\leq n$.
Assume that $p$ is an odd prime and $p^{\alpha}\parallel n$. By Euler's theorem $2^{\varphi(p^\alpha)}-1$ is a multiple of $p^{\alpha}$, and $2^{\varphi(p^\alpha)}-1$ is a divisor of $2^{n!}-1$, since $\varphi(p^{\alpha})\leq p^{\alpha}\leq n$. By the Chinese remainder theorem, $2^{n!}-1$ is a multiple of any odd prime power that exactly divides $n$, so $2^{n!}-1$ is a multiple of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's theorem, if $n$ is odd (i.e., relatively prime to $2$), then $2^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$.

$\phi(n)<n$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $\phi (n)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ with $p_1<\cdots<p_k$ odd primes. Now, note that since $n$ is odd, Euler's theorem yields:
$$
2^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n},
$$
where $\varphi(n)=\prod_{\ell=1}^k p_\ell^{\alpha_\ell-1}(p_\ell-1)$. Since $p_\ell^{\alpha_\ell-1}(p_\ell-1)<p_\ell^{\alpha_\ell}\leqslant n$, $p_\ell^{\alpha_\ell-1}(p_\ell-1)\mid n!$. In particular, $2^{n!}\equiv 1\pmod{p_\ell^{\alpha_\ell}}$. Finally, applying Chinese remainder theorem (since $p_i^{\alpha_i}$ and $p_j^{\alpha_j}$ are pairwise coprime), we deduce $2^{n!}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of giving something different I want to avoid the use of the Euler totient.

---

Because $2$ and $n$ are coprime, multiplication by $2$ is a permutation $\phi$ of the set $\Bbb{Z}_n$ of residue classes modulo $n$.

The order of the group, $S_n$, of bijections $\Bbb{Z}_n\to\Bbb{Z}_n$ is known to be $n!$. By Lagrange's theorem $\phi^{n!}$ is thus the identity mapping. In particular, 
$$1\equiv\phi^{n!}(1)\equiv2^{n!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! Your answers and/or hints were more than welcome! I must admit I completely forget to re-read Euler's theorem and well,  the demo is really direct from there. Mr. Lahtonen's answer with Lagrange's theorem is a clever and different way to think this problem through! Once again, I thank you all for the time you took and your answers:)